# LINQ query, retrieving the last x distinct data from the rows in tables

Tags: c#

here is my question, thanks in advance for your answers. I have three tables, Repair, Status, and the many to many table RepairStatus. Table RepairStatus consists of 4 properties:

```
public class RepairStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int RepairStatusId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Repair")]
    public int RepairId { get; set; }

    public virtual Repair? Repair { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Status")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual Status? Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Below are sample data and desired result. Suppose I have 7 rows in my RepairStatus table:

```
RepairStatusId    RepairId    StatusId    DateTime 
    1                5          1         2022/05/27 18:20:00
    2                5          2         2022/05/28 18:20:00
    3                4          3         2022/06/15 18:20:00
    4                5          4         2022/06/17 18:20:00
    5                5          5         2022/06/18 18:20:00
    6                6          3         2022/07/25 18:20:00
    7                6          1         2022/08/25 18:20:00
```

Now I want to retrieve the last x rows (x marks the number of rows with different distinct RepairId, no duplicates). In the aforementioned example, the expected output would be:

```
RepairStatusId    RepairId    StatusId    DateTime 
    3                4          3         2022/06/15 18:20:00
    5                5          5         2022/06/18 18:20:00
    7                6          1         2022/08/25 18:20:00
```

Normally I would create another property of type bool and then this filtering would not be a problem, but this is project that I inherited...

Comment: All you need is to `ORDER BY` the `RepairStatusId` value and take the first N rows, e.g. `await db.Repairs.OrderByDescending( r => r.RepairStatusId ).Take( 3 ).ToListAsync()`.

Comment: How about : `repairStatuses.GroupBy(rs => rs.RepairId).SelectMany(groups => groups.OrderByDesc(rs => rs.DateTime).Take(x))`

Comment: @Dai What about the Distinct requirement on RepairId ?

Comment: But this would give me duplicate, since it would give me two rows with RepairId 6...and no row with RepairId 4.?

Comment: @Irwene Hmm, you're right. But the OP didn't describe how duplicates should be filtered...

Comment: Don't have the time to setup a test project to confirm my comment above, If I find time this afternoon I'll give it some more thought

Comment: @Irwene - i tried your solution, it doesnt work - either rewrite the query...

Comment: Did it finally, here it is:  var results = _db.RepairStatus.GroupBy(x => x.RepairId)
             .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(x => 
              x.RepairStatusId).FirstOrDefault())
             .ToList();

Comment: @PeroKvrgavi Nice, now what you could do is create an answer with your solution and some explanation, then accept it, so that someone with a similar problem can quickly see how you resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it finally, the query should go like this:

```
var results = _db.RepairStatus.
              .GroupBy(x => x.RepairId)
              .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(x => 
              x.RepairStatusId).FirstOrDefault())
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
            List<RepairStatus> status = new List<RepairStatus>()
            {
                new RepairStatus() { RepairStatusId = 1, RepairId = 5, StatusId = 1 , DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/27/2022 18:20:00")},
                new RepairStatus() { RepairStatusId = 2, RepairId = 5, StatusId = 2 , DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/28/2022 18:20:00")},
                new RepairStatus() { RepairStatusId = 3, RepairId = 4, StatusId = 3 , DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/15/2022 18:20:00")},
                new RepairStatus() { RepairStatusId = 4, RepairId = 5, StatusId = 4 , DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/17/2022 18:20:00")},
                new RepairStatus() { RepairStatusId = 5, RepairId = 5, StatusId = 5 , DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/18/2022 18:20:00")},
                new RepairStatus() { RepairStatusId = 6, RepairId = 6, StatusId = 3 , DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/25/2022 18:20:00")},
                new RepairStatus() { RepairStatusId = 7, RepairId = 6, StatusId = 1 , DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/25/2022 18:20:00")},
            };

            var results = status
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.RepairStatusId)
                .GroupBy(x => x.RepairId)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .OrderBy(x => x.RepairStatusId)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: nope, it doesnt give the expected result, though it gives different repair ids, but tnx for your answer:)

Comment: Which items do you want as LAST?  It took the latest by date.  If you want something different than you have to change the OrderByDescending to different criteria.

Comment: i want RepairStatusIds last, and I tried orderbydescending with that parameter

Comment: Then use .OrderByDescending(x => x.RepairStatusId).  I updated code and order results by RepairStatusId

Comment: did that and it does not work:(

Comment: I tried last instead of x.First(), which wolud give me the desired result, since the code above gives first RepairIds, but then i get warning - rewrite the query to apply orderby operation on the sequence before calling 'lastordefault'

Comment: Change the OrderBy instead.  My updated code give right results.